# Not getting desired values in input fields React redux or ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

[image][image]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
let _ = require('lodash');

import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {fetchedZonesEdit} from '../../actions/';

class InfoRow extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props); 
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {

        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                  {this.props.zone}
                </td>
                <td>{this.props.zoneValue}
                <input type="text"
                   className="form-control"
                   defaultValue={this.props.zoneValue}
                   value={this.props.name}
                   name={this.props.zone}
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

class ZoneDetailsEdit extends Component {

    render() {

        const rows = [];
        let a = this.props.ezn;
        

       Object.keys(this.props.ezn).map((keyName, keyIndex) =>{

          return rows.push(<InfoRow zone={keyName} zoneValue={a[keyName].toString()} key={keyIndex}/>)
       });

        return (


            <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="">

                  <table className="table table-clear">
                    <tbody>
                      {rows}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                 </div>
                 <div className="row px-1" >
                      <div className="px-2">
                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-info">Save</button>
                 </div></div>
          </div>

        )

    }


}

class ZoneDetailEditComponent extends Component {

  componentWillMount = () => {
        this.props.fetchedZonesEdit(this.props.location.query.id);
    };

  
  render() {
    
    return (
        <div className="container px-3 mr-3">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><h1>Edit Tag Information</h1></div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
                { this.props.ezn != null?
            <div>
                <ZoneDetailsEdit ezn={this.props.ezn}/>
            </div> :
                    <center><br /><h1><img src={'img/avatars/default.gif'} alt="Loading"/><br />Loading</h1></center>

            }
        </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        ezn: state.zones
    }

}


function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchedZonesEdit: fetchedZonesEdit}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(ZoneDetailEditComponent);
```

This is the snippet i provided
what I'm doing right now is i had fetched the data from the api and was shown in the input fields but the issue is data is fetched correctly but when i print outside input fields it works fine but when i enter in input fields as default value it doesn't works
screenshot also provided
when opened the page default values are set of previous page but when it is refreshed it works fine

Comment: (consider adding the javascript tag to this question)

Comment: Don't use both `value` and `defaultValue`. That does not make sense.

Comment: provide the solution then if u know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a controlled component you need not use defaultValue, assigning the props passed down to the value will suffice.

Also using redux, a better practice is to store the UI state in localState and all others in the redux store.

To do that you need to dispatch an action that updates the corresponsing reducer after passing the values to the topmost parent

Also you are not passing any prop as `name` to the `InfoRow` component and since defaultValue is rendered only at the time of create, you do not see the update.

You code must look something like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
let _ = require('lodash');

import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {fetchedZonesEdit} from '../../actions/';

class InfoRow extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props); 
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {

        this.props.handleChange(this.props.zone, event.target.value);


    }

    render() {
        return (

            <tr>
                <td>
                  {this.props.zone}
                </td>
                <td>{this.props.zoneValue}
                <input type="text"
                   className="form-control"
                   value={this.props.zoneValue}
                   name={this.props.zone}
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

class ZoneDetailsEdit extends Component {

    handleChange(zone, value) {
         //pass it to the parent and then fire an action from there to update this value in the store

    }
    render() {

        const rows = [];
        let a = this.props.ezn;


       Object.keys(this.props.ezn).map((keyName, keyIndex) =>{

          return rows.push(<InfoRow zone={keyName} zoneValue={a[keyName].toString()} handleChange={()=> this.handleChange}key={keyIndex}/>)
       });

        return (


            <div className="col-md-6">
                <div className="">

                  <table className="table table-clear">
                    <tbody>
                      {rows}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                 </div>
                 <div className="row px-1" >
                      <div className="px-2">
                        <button className="btn btn-sm btn-info">Save</button>
                 </div></div>
          </div>

        )

    }


}
```

Also there is no need for you to bind the lifeCycle function with `arrows`

Comment: Try this, if you need any help let me know

Answer (score 2):

`defaultValue` should be used only on [Uncontrolled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

Instead of using `defaultValue`, assign a default value to the `name` in your store.

Also, don't use `this.setState` if you are using redux. You are assigning the new value to `this.state.zone` which you never read.